# Call Recording failed with java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I am working with `android.media.MediaRecorder` for recording voice call, and got stuck at exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException`, please help

**Code**

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(SERVICE_TAG,"onStartCommand [flags: " + flags + ", startId: " + startId + "]");

        initMediaRecorder("onStartCommand");

        if(PojoClass.isRecording){
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }else{
            try {
                //create Sound File.
                Recording = createOutputFile();
                //work for recording
                if(Recording != null){
                    iRecorder.reset();
                    //iRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);  //1 -> mono and 2-> Stereo
                    iRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    iRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); //Line #82
                    iRecorder.setOutputFile(Recording.getAbsolutePath());
                    Log.d(MEDIA_RECORDER_TAG,"Recorder Set\nAudioChannels: 1 (mono)" +
                            "\nAudioSource: " + MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT +
                            "\nAudioEncoder: " + MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT +
                            "\nOutputFile: " + Recording.getAbsolutePath());

                    iRecorder.setOnErrorListener(this);
                    iRecorder.setOnInfoListener(this);
                    try {
                        iRecorder.prepare();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        iRecorder.release();
                        iRecorder = null;
                    }

                    //start recording
                    iRecorder.start();
                    PojoClass.isRecording = true;
                    //Notify user that Call is being recorded.
                    NotifyUserOnRecording(true);
                }
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                iRecorder.release();
                iRecorder = null;
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

**LogCat**

```
01-19 14:44:43.949    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication D/iRecordCall﹕ onCreate
01-19 14:44:43.949    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication D/MEDIA_RECORDER_TAG﹕ MediaRecorder is initialize at [onCreate]
01-19 14:44:43.951    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication D/iRecordCall﹕ onStartCommand [flags: 0, startId: 1]
01-19 14:44:43.951    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication D/MEDIA_RECORDER_TAG﹕ MediaRecorder is initialize at [onStartCommand]
01-19 14:44:43.961    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication E/MediaRecorder﹕ setAudioEncoder called in an invalid state(2)
01-19 14:44:43.961    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication W/System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException
01-19 14:44:43.963    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(Native Method)
01-19 14:44:43.963    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.myapplication.recorderservice.iRecordCall.onStartCommand(iRecordCall.java:82)
01-19 14:44:43.963    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3010)
01-19 14:44:43.963    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
01-19 14:44:43.963    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1442)
01-19 14:44:43.963    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-19 14:44:43.963    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-19 14:44:43.963    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-19 14:44:43.963    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-19 14:44:43.963    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-19 14:44:43.963    2191-2191/com.example.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MediaRecorder` has to be in the "**DataSourceConfigured**" state if you want to call

```
iRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

So before this line you need to set the format of the file you want to generate, for example:

```
iRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
```

See also this link to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html), especially the state diagram.

Comment: @0x0nosugure Thanks, it worked for me but also shown same exception on `iRecorder.start()` as **MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -38**

Comment: @iSandeep - you placed the "iRecorder.prepare()" in a try-catch-block. Can you determine whether it was successful?

Comment: @0x0nosugure Yes it is Successfull

Comment: @iSandeep - there are some questions on SO where for example the camera was blocked, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23980230/5015207)